Get number of OpenWire connections via Jolokia
We upgraded from ActiveMQ Classic to ActiveMQ Artemis and one challenge that we have is monitoring the number of OpenWire clients via Jolokia.
ActiveMQ Classic reported connection info and it was easy to parse out the number of OpenWire clients. How does one do that in ActiveMQ Artemis?

The built-in hawtio console doesn't work - I am guessing because of large number of queues that we have. Just sits there.. the network tab shows continual download of 7MB data blobs from Artemis

There are ways to deal with the slowdown of the Hawtio web console in use-cases with lots of addresses, queues, etc. You should post a separate question about that.

The listConnections management operation will give you information you want. It is exposed via Jolokia (just like all management methods). You can invoke it, for example, via curl and then parse the result, for example, via jq:
curl -s -H "Origin: http://localhost" -u myUsername:myPassword "http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia/exec/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"0.0.0.0\"/listConnections/\{\"field\":\"protocol\",\"operation\":\"EQUALS\",\"value\":\"OPENWIRE\"\}/1/10" | jq '.value | fromjson | .count'

